# Using Scipy Optimize Minimize

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, minimize

I'm trying to optimize a function with **scipy.optimize.minimize** but I can't figure out what goes where, alternatively getting the error messages *"ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence"* or *"TypeError: llf() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"*

My code is what follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

u = np.random.normal(0, 1, 50)
t = 25
x = t*u/(1-u)
x = np.sort(x, axis=0)

theta = list(range(1, 1001, 1))
theta = np.divide(theta, 10)
xv, tv = np.meshgrid(x, theta)
xt_sum = xv + tv # Each *theta* has been added to all values of *x*
xt_sum_inv = 1/xt_sum
xt_sum_n = np.sum(xt_sum_inv, axis=1) # This is a length 1000 vector where each entry is equal to sum(1/(theta + x))

def llf(arg):
    return (-1 * (50/arg - 2 * xt_sum_n))

res = scipy.optimize.minimize(llf, theta, method='BFGS')
```

*theta* is what I am trying to optimize for.

I feel I might have either my positional arguments wrong, or my variables or function output is the wrong data structure. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html),

> scipy.optimize.minimize
>
> Minimization of scalar function of one or more variables

The keyword above is scalar. Your function does not return a single value (a scalar), but many, i.e. it returns a vector.

Whatever you are trying to achieve, you are using the wrong numerical function, or you are defining the wrong target function, i.e. your `llf()`.